# How to use PhpUnit mocking methods within codeception yii2 tests

Tags: testing, yii2, mocking, codeception

I need to use PHPUnit mocking methods like `expect($this->once())->returnSelf();` in codecept/yii2 tests. Cannot find any way  to call them. The Stub library of codeception does not have as many way to mock a method.

Although phpunit is wrapped by codeception I neither can find a way to use phpunit with yii 2 for API testing using `sendPost` etc.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The `Codeception\Test\Unit` class indirectly extends `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`.
You should be able to use PHPUnit way of creating mock object and then you can set up its methods:

```php
public function testMyTestCase()
{
    $mockedObject = $this->createMock(MockedClassOrInterface::class);
    $mockedObject->expects($this->once())
        ->method('methodName')
        ->willReturnSelf();
    // ... rest of the test case code
}
```